# How to mount cloned LV with UUID identical to already mounted LV

Tags: lvm

I made a bootable backup of my encrypted drive using dd:

```
> sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=64k status=progress
```

After checking that I can boot from the clone, I booted back into the original drive and tried to mount the clone using vgimportclone:

```
> sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc5 sdc5_crypt
> sudo lvm
lvm> vgimportclone /dev/mapper/sdc5_crypt
lvm> pvscan --cache
lvm> vgchange -a y
lvm> quit
> mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root /mnt
```

The VG names and VG & PV UUIDs on the clone are now different from those on the original drive, but the LV UUIDs are the same. The VG name for the original drive is `ubuntu-vg` and for the new drive it's `ubuntu-vg11`. I altered /boot/grub.cfg on the unencrypted partition of the cloned disk to reflect these changes and ensure it is still bootable.
After checking that the clone is still bootable (it is), I booted back into the original drive, and tried mounting the clone:

```
> sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc5 sdc5_crypt
> mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root /mnt
```

At first it appeared to work, but on closer inspection of the contents of /mnt I realized that it had actually mounted the original LV there (which is already mounted on /, and had some new files added to it since first creating the clone).
So the next thing I tried was changing the filesystem UUID of the clone using `tune2fs`:

```
umount /mnt
tune2fs -U random /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root
```

I checked that the filesystem UUID on the clone (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root) differs from that of the original (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)
However the problem persists, so I assume it must be due to the identical LV UUIDs.
Everything I've read online suggests it's not possible to change LV UUIDs, so I wonder is there any other way around this problem? How can I mount my cloned drive at the same time as the original?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the UUID of the LVs on the clone, and get it to mount at the same time as the original without conflict.
Here's how I did it:

1. I attached a different drive with a copy of Ubuntu installed and booted into it.
2. I attached the cloned drive, and opened the encrypted partition: `sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sd5 sdc5_crypt`
3. This automatically created links for the LVs: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root` & `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-swap`
4. I then removed the LVs on the clone: `sudo lvremove ubuntu-vg11`
5. Then I checked the lvm archive, which keeps a record of all changes: `sudo ls -l /etc/lvm/archive`
6. I made a note of the most recent archive file for the `ubuntu-vg11` group, and edited it, altering the UUIDs of the LVs listed in the file.
7. Then I restored the LVs from that archive file: `sudo vgcfgrestore ubuntu-vg11 -f /etc/lvm/archive/ubuntu-vg11_00001-123456789.vg`
8. Check the UUIDs of the LVs: `sudo lvscan && sudo lvdisplay`
   (the newly altered LVs were not listed by `lvs` for some reason, but I was still able to mount them without problems).
9. Check that they can be mounted OK: `sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg11-root /media/sdc5`
10. Unmount and reboot: `sudo umount /media/sdc5`

It now seems to work fine, and I can mount both the clone and the original at the same time with no problems.